# How do you change apt sources in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, apt

I would like to update my sources.list to use servers closer to me, so that apt_update is faster.

Typically, I ssh into my server and just modify /etc/apt/sources.list, but since I am using chef, I would like to put it in the recipe.

In my recipes/default.rb:

```
#I am trying to modify the sources.list file in apt before I run apt-get update
cookbook_file '/etc/apt/sources.list' do
  source 'sources.list'  
end

apt_update 'all platforms' do
  action :update
end
```

It appears that chef is not using the sources I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use [notification](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications) (or subscription, your choice):

```
cookbook_file '/etc/apt/sources.list' do
  source 'sources.list'  
  notifies :update, "apt_update[all platforms]"
end

apt_update 'all platforms' do
  action :nothing
end
```

In result, on `sources.list` file change, notification to `apt_update[all_platforms]` will be issued. If you want to run `apt_update` immediately, add proper keyword to notification (read the doc).

Sidenote: I'm not sure why are you modifying `sources.list`, if you are adding an additional repositories use `apt_repository` resource from the [`apt`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/apt) cookbook.

Comment: The `apt_repository` resource is now available in Chef core.

Comment: Thanks Szymon. To answer your sidenote, the code is being hosted on a server in China, where the connection to US servers is spotty. Rather than adding new repositories, I was just looking to replace the default ones that ship with Ubuntu 14.04 with mirrors located in China.

Comment: A follow up - I tried your method

cookbook_file '/etc/apt/sources.list' do
    source 'sources.list'
    notifies :update, 'apt_update[all platforms]', :immediate
end



apt_update 'all platforms' do
    subscribes :update, 'cookbook_file[/etc/apt/sources.list]', :immediate
    action :nothing
end

But based on the speed (10 minutes to update) ... it appears to still be pulling from the default http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu rather than the mirror I specified. Do you know if the apt_update resource uses etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: `apt_update` with action `:update`, should run `apt-get -q update`. So if your file has proper syntax it should work fine. Check if you don't have any additional repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You can also check chef debug logs, maybe you have second resource which is updating your sources list.

Comment: This is not perfect example but some parts of it can be useful to you - I pull it from one of my first recipes - https://gist.github.com/gogoluxecs/34c48042776f14826e3b45a08688a783